# Why my onClickListener should double click?

Tags: android

I added onClickListener to NavLinearLayout which I wrote by extend LinearLayout,and everytime it should double click then the functions inside can work.But that function means it can work when click only once.Why?
This is my NavLinearLayout

```
public class NavLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

public NavLinearLayout(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public NavLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    // do whatever you want with the event
    // and return true so that children don't receive it
    return true;
}}
```

This is the MainActivity code:

```
boutiqueLL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            setFlagTrue(Navigation.Boutique.getPosition());
            setBtnLine();
        }

    });private void setFlagTrue(int position) {
    sousuoFlag = position == 4 ? true : false;
    dingyueFlag = position == 3 ? true : false;
    fenleiFlag = position == 2 ? true : false;
    boutiqueFlag = position == 1 ? true : false;
}private void setBtnLine() {
    Log.d("test",(boutiqueFlag?"true":"false")+" : "
            +(fenleiFlag?"true":"false")+" : "
            +(dingyueFlag?"true":"false")+" : "
            +(sousuoFlag?"true":"false"));
    if (sousuoFlag) {
        sousuoLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_page, new SearchFragment(mdb));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    } else {
        sousuoLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    if (dingyueFlag) {
        dingyueLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_page, new SubscribeFragment(mdb));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        dingyueLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    if (fenleiFlag) {
        fenleiLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_page, new FenLeiFragment(hanlder,mdb));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        fenleiLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    if (boutiqueFlag) {
        boutiqueLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_page, new BoutFragmentNew(mdb));
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        boutiqueLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us clearer what is the problem? Is it not working when you double tap, or should it not work when you double tap?

Comment: I should double tap to let it work,but that function means only click once can make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener.It works,but I don't know why my OnClickListener needs double click now.

Answer (score 1):

For ur problem this maybe a explanation:
As I can see you have extended LinearLayout which is providing InterceptTouchEvents(), which works for touch events.
So on this layout you are having a touchevent listener and a clickevent listener, in this case when you do click on layout firstly the touch event is invoked and then second time click event is invoked.
Thats why your touchevent works.